# Stream and download audio from URL

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am developing app that search for song and able play and download music/song.I used this url http://tinysong.com/Phdj , this is redirecting to music web page and there its playing song. i used below code to play song.

```
    //play music
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try{
         mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://tinysong.com/Phdj");
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                e.printStackTrace();    
                }catch (IllegalStateException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new   MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() 
                            {

                                @Override
                                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
                                {
                                    mp.start();
                                }
                            });
```

ERROR:
09-21 11:26:49.674: I/MediaPlayer(6735): setLPAflag() in
09-21 11:26:49.674: I/MediaPlayer(6735): mContext is null, can't getMirrorDisplayStatus!!!
09-21 11:26:49.674: I/MediaPlayer(6735): setLPAflag() out
09-21 11:26:58.693: E/MediaPlayer(6735): error (1, -2147483648)
09-21 11:26:58.693: E/MediaPlayer(6735): Error (1,-2147483648)

Is AndroidMedia Library play only .mp3 format? Can i play music from above Url?How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed the context in `setDataSource()`

Try this

```
String path="http://tinysong.com/Phdj";

    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(path);

            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            try {

                mp.setDataSource(this, myUri);
                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        mp.start();
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                mp.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: getting this error: 09-21 17:35:50.315: E/MediaPlayer(30342): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://tinysong.com/Phdj
09-21 17:35:58.293: E/MediaPlayer(30342): error (1, -2147483648)
09-21 17:35:58.333: E/MediaPlayer(30342): Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: Have you create the reference to the MediaPlayer ?

Comment: Sorry am new to media player...what that reference to media player?

Comment: 09-21 17:35:50.315: E/MediaPlayer(30342): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: tinysong.com/Phdj 09-21 17:35:58.293: E/MediaPlayer(30342): error (1, -2147483648) 09-21 17:35:58.333: E/MediaPlayer(30342): Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: is media player only supports .mp3 file? can you please check that url and confirm me that url is good to use for media players?

Comment: i already checked that, so i got that doubt , but i need to play that song..is there any way to do that? can you please help me?

Comment: or is there any api that i can use for free which gives .mp3 muisc